# Get all quote id from custom column data magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, products, quote, sales-quote

I have the following code. Where I pass a device id which is stored as a custom column in sales_quote and get all the quote ids to that device id.
By trying the below code I am able to get only first occurrence of quote id.

Can anyone please help.
Thanks

```
$deviceId=$device_id;
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($deviceId,'device_id');//here device_id is feild in database
    $cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    $pid = $item->getQuoteId();
    }
```

Comment: Using **load()**  will return one model object. Try to get collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
$deviceId=$device_id;
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('device_id',$deviceId);
foreach ($quote as $item) {
    $pid[] = $item->getQuoteId();
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your code is doing and how this solves the OP's question